# get the image url in the javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

I am using Rails 4.x, in assets I have a `.js` file, which displays a popup, which contains an image. It works fine in the local development but as soon as I deploy it to the `heroku` image is not loaded.

I have precompiled the assets in `*config/initializers/assets.rb*`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( popup.js)
```

This is the snippet where I provide path to the image in the `.js' file

```
var logo = '/assets/logo.png',
```

Please bear in mind that appending the `.erb` is not very preferable option

Comment: not difficult to inspect image in browser dev tools to see what failed url is and adjust accordingly  assuming that file exists

Comment: in the deployment environment in public folder rails appends to the file name the MD5 hash and therefore the image can't be found

Comment: Did you install the 12factor gem and also run 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production' then do a git add and commit before pushing to heroku?  Just listing them for precomp. isn't enough.